# Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python-3.x, macos, numpy, terminal, pip

I saw several posts regarding this issue, I tried almost all solutions but end up with the same error.  I am trying to install numpy with pip 20.2.4. I got this below error message.

> Failed to build numpy
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

I tried all the below commands but I am running out of ideas:

> pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

> sudo pip install numpy --no-binary :all:

I always get the same message:

> Failed to build numpy
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Do you have other ideas to solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: why are you using `--no-binary :all:`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar error of what I think you got.
[image]

I've solved it by installing the "Build Tools para Visual Studio 2019" and installing the section of desktop C++ compiler.

### Steps

1. Go to Microsoft Studio [Downloads](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) and search down in section "All Downloads" > "Tools for Visual Studio 2019".
2. Download "Build Tools para Visual Studio 2019".
3. Install C++ compiler package (Elevated privileges are required).
4. Retry pip instalation `pip install numpy`
5. Enjoy.